# Multiple column legends in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

I created a single stacked horizontal bar chart which illustrates the values in a (normalized) series using:

```py
data = df['state'].value_counts(normalize=True).to_frame()
data.T.plot.barh(stacked=True, figsize=(18,3))
```

which produced the following output:

[image]

I'd like to arrange the legend labels into a few columns and display them *below* the x-axis. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Using Matplotlib directly (i.e., no plotting from df object), is it an option for you?

Comment: yes, and @JohanC's answer was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `plt.legend(...)` setting the number of columns and the legend's position.  This will erase the existing legend and create it again.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

states = ["Avaloria", "Eldoria", "Mystara", "Zephyria", "Nimoria", "Dragoria", "Frostvale", "Solaris", "Thundara",
          "Luminara", "Shadowmere", "Celestia", "Aquaria", "Pyronia", "Galewind", "Starfell", "Moonhaven", "Ironforge"]
prob = np.random.rand(len(states)) ** 2 + 0.05
prob /= prob.sum()
df = pd.DataFrame({'state': np.random.choice(states, 500, p=prob)})
data = df['state'].value_counts(normalize=True).to_frame()
data.T.plot.barh(stacked=True, figsize=(15, 3))
plt.legend(ncol=6, loc='upper left', bbox_to_anchor=(0, -0.11))
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: moving a pandas' legend]